# Solving recurrence relations of type $S_n-7S_{n-1}+10S_{n-2}=5\cdot 3^n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I know how to solve this kind of equasions 
$$S_n-7S_{n-1}+10S_{n-2}=5\cdot 3^n$$ $$S_0=0, S_1=1$$ for example...but when there is a constant (example:$(3^n+5))$ or  $(5\cdot 3^n)$ i don't know how to solve it. Any tips.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: It's still method of undetermined coefficients.  For $3^n + 5$, you guess a particular solution of the form $c_1 \cdot 3^n + c_2$; for $5 \cdot 3^n$ you guess a particular solution of the form $c \cdot 3^n$.

Comment: isn't  c* 3^n  only for 3^n , not for 5*3^n?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the characteristic polynomial is $z^2-7z+10 = (z-2)(z-5)$, the solutions of
$$ S_{n}-7 S_{n-1} + 10 S_{n-2} = 0 $$
have the form $S_n = \alpha 2^n+\beta 5^n$. By direct inspection a solution of
$$ S_{n}-7 S_{n-1} + 10 S_{n-2} = 5\cdot 3^n $$
is given by $S_n=-\frac{45}{2}\cdot3^n$, hence the set of solutions of the previous recurrence is given by
$$ S_n = \alpha 2^n+\beta 5^n-\frac{45}{2}3^n $$
and by imposing $S_0=0$ and $S_1=1$ we get:
$$\boxed{ S_n = \color{red}{\frac{44}{3}2^n + \frac{47}{6} 5^n -\frac{45}{2} 3^n}.} $$

Comment: how did you get this -45/2 ???

Comment: @SimonJachson: by looking at solutions of the form $C\cdot 3^n$.

Comment: So you are geting A2^n + B5^n- C3^n . And from where have you found the C ?

Comment: A friend of mine would say *non siete in grado nemmeno di togliervi un dito dal culo da soli* but I won't translate that. Assume that $S_n=K\cdot 3^n$. For which value of $K$ do we have $S_n-7S_{n-1}+10 S_{n-2}=5\cdot 3^n$? Just $K=-\frac{45}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&S_{n} - 7S_{n - 1} + 10S_{n - 2} = 5 \times 3^n\implies
3^{-n}S_{n} - {7 \over 3}\bracks{3^{-\pars{n - 1}}S_{n - 1}} +
{10 \over 9}\bracks{3^{-\pars{n - 2}}S_{n - 2}} = 5
\\[5mm] & \implies
\bracks{3^{-n}S_{n} + {45 \over 2}} -
{7 \over 3}\bracks{3^{-\pars{n - 1}}S_{n - 1} + {45 \over 2}} +
{10 \over 9}\bracks{3^{-\pars{n - 2}}S_{n - 2} + {45 \over 2}} = 0
\end{align}

> The *characteristic equation* for $\ds{3^{-n}S_{n} + {45 \over 2}}$ has the roots $\ds{2/3}$ and $\ds{5/3}$:

\begin{align}
&3^{-n}S_{n} + {45 \over 2} = a\pars{2 \over 3}^{n} + b\pars{5 \over 3}^{n}
\implies
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{45 \over 2} & \ds{=} & \pars{a + b}
\\[2mm]
\ds{{1 \over 3} + {45 \over 2}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{2 \over 3}\,a + {5 \over 3}\,b}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm] &\ \implies\qquad
\left.\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{2a} & \ds{+} & \ds{2b} & \ds{=} & \ds{45}
\\
\ds{4a} & \ds{+} & \ds{10b} & \ds{=} & \ds{137}
\end{array}\right\}\quad\implies\quad
\pars{~a = {44 \over 3}\ \mbox{and}\ b =  {47 \over 6}~}
\\[5mm] &\ \implies
3^{-n}S_{n} + {45 \over 2} =
{44 \over 3}\,\pars{2 \over 3}^{n} + {47 \over 6}\,\pars{5 \over 3}^{n}
\\[5mm] &\ \implies
S_{n} + {45 \over 2}\,3^{n} =
{44 \over 3}\,2^{n} + {47 \over 6}\,5^{n}\implies
\bbx{S_{n} =
{44 \over 3}\,2^{n} - {45 \over 2}\,3^{n} + {47 \over 6}\,5^{n}}
\\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence can be thought of as a difference equation (discrete analog of a differential equation). Since the difference operator is linear the [$z$-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) is a particularly useful tool. Applying the transform we have

$$Z[S_n -7S_{n-1}+10S_{n-2}] = 5\cdot Z[3^n]$$

The RHS is
$$
Z[3^n] = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty\left(\frac{3}{z}\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-3z^{-1}}.
$$
Furthermore
$$
Z[S_{n-k}] = z^{-k}S(z). 
$$
You can solve for $S(z)$ and invert it to get $S_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to reduce it into the form you know how to solve:
\begin{align}
&S_{n+1}-7S_n+10S_{n-1}=5\cdot3^{n+1}\\
\implies &S_{n+1}-7S_n+10S_{n-1}=3(S_n-7S_{n-1}+10S_{n-2})\\
\implies &S_{n+1}-10S_n+31S_{n-1}-30S_{n-2}=0
\end{align}
So by solving the recursive polynomial, the solution is of the form $S_n=a2^n+b3^n+c5^n$. Satisfy $S_0,S_1$ and the original equation to get the required answer as $$\boxed{ S_n = \frac{44}{3}2^n-\frac{45}{2} 3^n+ \frac{47}{6} 5^n}$$